# GroupBy and Change the values of one columns

Tags: python, pandas

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhasS.png)

Hi dear coders, I need help from you as I don't know how to deal with it.
As you can see on my dataframe i have a column description and a column title.
I want for a same description , my title to be all the same.
I want to groupby description and give to "title" of this group all the same value.
By default, the first title value for each description group.

for exemple, for the description "L'eau de cologne, symbole incontournable..." I want all the titles to be "Eau de cologne Les exclusifs de Chanel 75ml..." (as its the first value)
The value "Eau de cologne Les exclusifs de Chanel 200ml..." will then be replaced by "Eau de cologne Les exclusifs de Chanel 75ml..."

Sorry I don't know if i explained it well

Comment: Please provide a sample dataframe as text along with expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution with some dummy data using `pandas.DataFrame.transform`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'title': ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5'],
                   'description': ['d1', 'd1', 'd1', 'd2', 'd2']})

  description title
0          d1    t1
1          d1    t2
2          d1    t3
3          d2    t4
4          d2    t5
```

We expect to replace `t2` and `t3` with `t1`, and `t5` with `t4`.

Code:

```
df['first_title'] = df.groupby('description').transform("first")

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  description title first_title
0          d1    t1          t1
1          d1    t2          t1
2          d1    t3          t1
3          d2    t4          t4
4          d2    t5          t4
```